# Problems passing sveltekit data to the frontend

Tags: sveltekit

I recently started learning Sveltekit and i adapted a small CRUD application that i made with express and PostgreSQL but i am not able to pass correctly the database data to the frontend. This is the code i wrote so far:

```
var query_output = undefined;

export const load = () => {
    return {query_output}
};

export const actions = {

    default: async (event) => {

        let form_input = await event.request.formData();

        let query = {
            text: "select * from ux_return_shipments($1, $2, $3, $4)",
            values: [form_input.get('beg-dep-date') || null, form_input.get('end-dep-date') || null, form_input.get('beg-arr-date') || null, form_input.get('end-arr-date') || null]
        }

        event.locals.pool.query(query)
            .then(result => {
                query_output = result.rows;})
    }

};
```

The problem is that the data sent to the frontend is not the same extracted from the database. I suspect that this is caused by the fact that the second export requires time while the first one is performed immediately, therefore the 'query_output' variable sent to the frontend is always late.

How can i sync the two steps? Currently i am using two different exports because the second one reads the data that the user inserted in a form and also contains the db connection data through the locals attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can i sync the two steps?

You don't. `load` is for loading page data without any user input, form actions are for responding to form submissions from user interactions. They are completely separate and do not share state.

The action should return its own data which is passed to the page component as the `form` property. Data from `load` is passed to the `data` property.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately i still have some problems passing the data to the frontend: i modified the second export like this ".then(result => {return { output: result.rows };})" but in the frontend i still don't receive anything if i write "export let form;" in the script part. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You are not retuning any data that way, You are just returning data from the inner function (within then). Your function is async, you can just do: `const result = await event.locals.pool.query(query); return result.rows;`. Please read [up on that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) if you are unsure about how async/await works in relation to promises.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried with your approach and now everything works!

Comment: Glad it helped. If that sufficiently answered your question, you can accept the answer using the checkmark outline to its side.